# I Already Installed Playsound But It Still Gives Me This Error

Tags: python, module

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/icykaido/PythonCodes/practice/01_module_usage.py", line 1, in 
from playsound import playsound # pip install playsound
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'playsound'

Comment: run ``pip freeze`` & check if the package is getting listed.

Comment: @sushanth Yeah It Does

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.